# MySQL C connector: executing queries from separate threads

Tags: mysql-connector, mariadb, mysql

I create the connection to the server in the main thread of application:

```
ClassA::ClassA(void)
{
    mpMySQL = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (!mysql_thread_safe())
    {
        // Error;
    }
}
```

Later there is a connection to the server:

```
void ClassA::OpenConnection(/*inParams*/)
{
    .....
    mysql_real_connect(mpMySQL, /*inParams*/);
    .....
}
```

Now I use mpMySQL to execute queries:

```
MyRes ClassA::SQLQuery(MyString inQuery)
{
   ...
    if (!mysql_real_query(mpMySQL, inQuery, inQuery.length()))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

While the app uses the object of ClassA in the main thread - all works fine.

But if the method

```
A->SQLQuery()
```

invokes from the thread - the application crashes on execution

```
mysql_real_query()
```

======

As I understand this happens because the mpMySQL was initialized in one thread and was used in another. Am I right?

Is the way to do this trick? Or I should initialize MYSQL structure in every separated thread (and make separate connection) to execute queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_thread_init()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-thread-init.html) is the trick. You need to execute it for every thread that is using C API.
mysql_init() does it implicitly.